# SaxParserFactory not found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sax

I am starting to work with XML files. So i thought, it would be good to start with a simple example.
But for some reason i cant import the necessary files.

This is what my project looks like

[image: my project]

In the tutorial i checked, it said that the import should be automaticlly an option from eclipse, well this is not the case.
Take a look at the options that eclipse gives me.

[image: Screenshot]

What am I missing?

Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: It is `SAXParserFactory` not `SaxParserFactory`, case is important in Java.

Comment: By the way, having more than one _JRE System Library_ on the Java Build Path does not make sense.

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Comment: Yes, I was able to fix my problem.I picked the wrong JRE, when creating my project.

Comment: Glad you got it working!